# How to evaluate $\int_{C}{|y|ds}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

> Suppose a curve $C$ is given by the equation $(x^2+y^2)^2=R(x^2-y^2)$ where $R \in \mathbb{N} \backslash \lbrace 0\rbrace$. Evaluate the line integral $\displaystyle\int_{C}{|y|ds}$.

I let $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ and substitute them into the equation of $C$. Then I obtain $r=R \sqrt{\cos {2 \theta}}$. Then by using the definition of line integral $$
\int_C{f(x,y)ds=\int_a^b{f(x(t),y(t)||r'(t)||dt}}\;.
$$ (what I am doing is just parametrising the curve), I obtain $$\int_{C}{|y|ds=R^2}$$

Comment: Consider $R=1.$ Then the curve is $y=0$ and the integral must be $0.$

Comment: When $R=1$, why $y=0$?

Comment: @Idontknow: $x^2+y^2=x^2-y^2$ implies $y=0$

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk Then do you have any idea on how to evaluate this integral?

Comment: The exercise seems strange to me. For $R=0$ the curve is $y=0$ and for $R>1$ it is a union of two lines $y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{R+1}{R-1}}x.$ Thus the integral is just $+\infty$ for $R>1$ and $0$ for $R=1.$

Comment: sorry. i type the equation of the curve wrongly. Fixed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11518/discussion-between-yurii-savchuk-and-idonknow)